# Ractive views not tearing down as expected

Tags: ractivejs

My example is here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DCfkw

if you open up dev tools/console, you will see that all Ractive views go through their teardown cycle.

However, if you transpose lines 8 and 9 in the html panel (basically, put the each for model.grandChildTitles inside the closing the div tag), you will see that only the child goes through its teardown cycle.

I've narrowed it down to ractive.js line 11100 (v0.6.0, coming out of bower's -> ractive/ractive.js, if it makes any difference, though I see the same thing at http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js - serving 0.6.0 - line 11100) -

It would appear that when you're tearing down an element, if it has a fragment, ractive calls `this.fragment.unrender( false )`, automatically assuming that the fragment is not a view unto itself which should also be torn down.

Am I missing something here? At my first glance, it seems like a memory leak and something that would prevent me from doing any `onteardown`-type actions. Am I just doing it wrong?